# FORM VALIDATION using javascript by reyanpapa

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone, I encountered an error with regards to my program in html and javascript. When I submit input information in the fields of name, email and age, it prompts an error message, saying that I must choose a gender. However, after prompting the error message, the information in the name, email and age has been deleted. This is my code, I hope someone could help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Creating Page Title -->
    <title>validation</title>

    <!-- For Form validation we have to use JavaScript
    JavaScript needs only a browser to run, there is no need of 
    server to run JavaScript -->

    <script language="javascript">

        //Start JavaScript Function

        function verify() {

            //for field must take some input

            if (document.form1.name.value == "") {
                alert("Please give the name");
                document.form1.name.forus();
                return false;
            }

            //for field must take some input

            if (document.form1.email.value == "") {
                alert("Please give the email");
                return false;
            }

            // for field must take some input

            if (document.form1.age.value == "") {
                alert("Please give age");
                document.form1.age.focus();
                return false;
            }

            // alert thrown when age limit is below 18 and above 60

            if (document.form1.age.value < 18 || document.form1.age.value > 60) {
                alert("Please give Age range between 18 and 60");
                document.form1.age.focus();
                return false;
            }

            // Gender must be selected

            if (document.form1.gender[0].checked == false &&
                    document.form1.gender[1].checked == false) {
                alert("Please select gender");
                document.form1.gender.focus();
                return false;
            }

            // At least one checkbox must be checked

            if (document.form1.language1.checked == false &&
                    document.form1.language2.checked == false &&
                    document.form1.language3.checked == false) {
                alert("Please Select your choice of language(Atleast One)");
                return false;
            }

            //Country must be chosed

            if (document.form1.country.value == "") {
                alert("Please give country");
                document.form1.country.focus();
                return false;
            }

            //field must take some input

            if (document.form1.myaddress.value == "") {
                alert("Please give address");
                document.form1.myaddress.focus();
                return false;
            }

            //field must take some input

            if (document.form1.u_name.value == "") {
                alert("Please give username");
                document.form1.u_name.focus();
                return false;
            }

            //field must take some input

            if (document.form1.pass.value == "") {
                alert("Please give Password");
                document.form1.pass.focus();
                return false;
            }

            //password length must be greater than 5 characters

            if (document.form1.pass.value.lenght < 6) {
                alert("Please give a Password more than 5 characters");
                document.form1.pass.focus();
                return false;
            }

            // for field must take some input

            if (document.form1.r_pass.value == "") {
                alert("Please retype your password");
                document.form1.r_pass.focus();
                return false;
            }

            //password and confirm password must matched

            if ((document.form1.pass.value) != (document.form1.r_pass.value)) {
                alert("Your password does not match");
                document.form1.r_pass.value == "";
                document.form1.r_pass.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return( true );
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Creating Form -->
<form method="POST" action="" name="form1">

    <!-- Creating Table, having 11rows and 2 columns. -->
    <table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="7">

        <!-- Start First Row -->
        <tr>
            <!-- Creating First Column -->
            <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>

            <!-- Creating Second Columns -->
            <td>
                <!-- TextBox -->
                <input type="text" name="name"/>
            </td>
            <!-- Close First Row -->
        </tr>

        <!-- Creting First Columns -->
        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>

        <!-- Creating Second Columns -->
        <td>
            <!-- Textbox -->
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
        </td>
        <!-- Close Second row -->
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Age:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Textbox -->
                <input type="text" name="age" size="2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Gender:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Radio Butong -->
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>Female

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Language:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Check box -->
                <input type="checkbox" name="language1" value="Hindi"/>Hindi
                <input type="checkbox" name="language2" value="English"/>English
                <input type="checkbox" name="language3" value="Urdu"/>Urdu
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Country:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Combo Box -->
                <select name="country"/>
                <option value="" selected/>
                --Select--
                <option value="indi"/>
                India
                <option value="pakistan"/>
                Pakistan
                <option value="beangladesh"/>
                Beangladesh
                <option value="srilanka"/>
                Srilanka
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Address:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- TextArea -->
                <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="myaddress"/></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
            <td>

                <!-- Textbox -->
                <input type="text" name="u_name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Password Field -->
                <input type="password" name="pass"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Retype Password:</strong></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Password Field -->
                <input type="password" name="r_pass"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center">

            <td>
                <!--Submit Button, Function verify need to be called when we process
                submit button-->
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return (verify());"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <!--Reset Button-->
                <input type="reset">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--Table Close-->
    </table>

    <!--Form Close -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ then it might be easier for people to have a look.

Comment: Why this have 27k views - and no upvotes on answers or questions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code. You can build it on your own

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

//Start JavaScript Function

function verify()
{

//for field must take some input

if(document.forms["form1"]["name"].value=="")
{
alert("Please give the name");

return false;
}
}
</script>
    <form method="POST" action="test3.asp" name="form1" onSubmit="return verify()">

<!-- Creating Table, having 11rows and 2 columns. -->
<table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="7">

<!-- Start First Row -->
<tr>
<!-- Creating First Column -->
<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>

<!-- Creating Second Columns -->
<td>
<!-- TextBox -->
<input type ="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Try it out

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Here you can find both empty field and email validation.

In order to keep the field data, you can use cookie/session or if you just use in page validation, u can directly set the it via JavaScript code

```
this.form.elements["element_name"].value = 'Some Value';
```

Here, element_name should be replaced with current validating filed name and Some Value should be the current value of the current validating field.

Use this code before return false.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){
     if(document.forms[0].name.value=="" ){
      window.alert("name Required");
      return false;
    }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It is best to explain answers when you give them.